# Выбор между std::generate() и std::for_each()

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите выбрать реализацию метода из двух вариантов - calc1() и calc2():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <execution>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() {};
    ~Test() {};

    void add_eq(std::function<double(void)> f)
    {
        _equations.push_back(f);
    }

    // version 1
    std::vector<double>& calc1()
    {
        _v.resize(_equations.size());

        std::generate(
            std::execution::par,
            _v.begin(), _v.end(),
            [this, n = 0]() mutable
        {
            return _equations[n++](); 
        }
        );

        return _v;
    }

    // version 2
    std::vector<double>& calc2()
    {
        std::vector<int> inds(_equations.size());
        std::iota(inds.begin(), inds.end(), 0);

        _v.resize(_equations.size());

        std::for_each(
            std::execution::par,
            inds.begin(), inds.end(),
            [this](const int& n)
            {
                _v[n] = _equations[n]();
            }
        );

        return _v;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<double(void)>> _equations{};
    std::vector<double> _v{};
};
```

Оба ли варианта имеют право на жизнь (учитывая использование std::execution::par)?
И какой вариант более предпочтителен?
Меня смущают оба варианта, поэтому и решил посоветоваться.

Comment: В `for_each` подразумевается использование хранящегося значения, а в `generate` - нет. Хотя `inds` совершенно бессмыслен. А еще в контексте параллельного исполнения смущает совместное использование поля `n` - скорее всего, тут будет состояние гонки.

Comment: @user7860670 да, inds выглядит лишним, но как без него for_each реализовать я не придумал :). А что имеется ввиду под "подразумевается использование хранящегося значения"? Какого значения?

Comment: @user7860670 "n - скорее всего, тут будет состояние гонки" - вот именно это меня и смутило. На тестах вроде все в порядке. Но решил посоветоваться. Оба варианта смущают

Comment: Которое хранится в контейнере и передается внутрь функтора на каждой итерации, в данном случае значения, хранящиеся в inds.

Comment: * про состояние гонки тут имелось ввиду в первом случае `n++`

Comment: @user7860670 да, я понял. Меня этот момент тоже смущает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут больше [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) подойдёт

```
_v.resize(_equations.size());

std::transform(
    std::execution::par, 
    _equations.begin(), _equations.end(), 
    _v.begin(),
    [](const auto& f) { return f(); }
);
```

Comment: спасибо! Я чувствовал, что что-то не додумал. Это именно то, что надо.